# Junit testing - Actions for every test. How to minimize code?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, server, assert

I really didn't know how to describe it better in the title, but here it is explained:

I want to write tests for a Rest Api. Meaning: I log into the server for every test, run my call and log out. It would be way less code and more efficient, if I could somehow log into the server at the beginning of the test, do all my calls (still in seperate tests though) and then log out.

Is there a smart way to do this?

Thanks for every reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at annotation tags? 
i.e. @Before and @After tags

So for example:

```
@Before
private void loginToServer() throws Exception {
   /* Some code to do your login 
    and some code to do your repetitive tests
}

@Test
private void testEvents() {
//// Your test code 
}

@After
private void logoutServer() throws Exception {
/// Code to logout of your server
}
```

This way your code will always do the Before tag before it runs anything you set in the @Test class. And your @After class will always logout when finished.

Answer (score 0):

You should use @BeforeClass and @AfterClass.